# Act led not on but raspberry pi works fine with retropie

Tags: pi-3, retropie, activity-led

I have a raspberry pi 3b v1.2 that has retropie running on it, the red led lights up nice and bright but the green ACT led does not. It runs retropie fine but I can’t tell when my file transfers are being completed because the act light never shows me sd card activity(or anything for that matter). I’ve tested the led with a multimeter and it works fine, it just won’t light on its own. Please help this is making it really hard for me to do rom file transfers.

Comment: what is the output of `cat /sys/devices/platform/leds/leds/ACT/trigger`

Comment: The ACT LED is effectively useless. I always use it for something meaningful. If you have problems you need to post meaningful diagnostics and details of what you are doing.